# How to turn files listed in dictionary values to links and open using software assoc with that file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have file names listed in the value of my "files" dictionary. How can I code it that when the dictionary returns those values (files) it returns them as some sort of a hyperlink that when you click the link the OS will automatically open the software associated with that file?

I know this will not work in terminal but right now I'm using Jupyter Notebook. Also, the code will be in the same directory as the files - thank you.

```
def concept(phrase):

# split var(phrase) at spaces and assign to var(words)
words = phrase.split()

# use this to list python file titles and links to open them in a new tab
files    = {1:"file0001.txt",
            2:"file0002.txt",
            3:"file0003.txt",
            4:"file0004.txt",
            5:"file0005.txt",
            6:"file0006.txt",
            7:"file0007.txt",    
            8:"file0008.txt",
            9:"file0009.txt"}

# change keys to searchable simple keyword phrases. 
concepts = {'GAMES':[1,2,4,3,3],
            'BLACKJACK':[5,3,5,3,5],
            'MACHINE':[4,9,9,9,4],
            'DATABASE':[5,3,3,3,5],
            'LEARNING':[4,9,4,9,4]}

# iterate through all var(words) found in var(word)
for word in words:
# convert to uppercase, search var(word) in dict 'concepts', if not found return not found"
    if word.upper() not in concepts:
        print("'{}':Not Found in Database" .format(word)) not in concepts
    else:
# for matching keys in dict 'concept' list values in dict 'files'
        for pattern in concepts[word.upper()]:
            print(files[pattern])

# return input box at end of query        
while True:
    concept(input("Enter Concept Idea: "))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't create a custom link in a console, even in a jupyter notebook (except for web links, they are automatically converted to hyperlinks). However, you can open a file in python with this:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call("start " + filename, shell=True) # On windows
subprocess.call("open " + filename, shell=True) # On Mac
```

Hope it helps.